# ASP.Net ViewState Gets Reset

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm creating a website to work with a game app where alliances can battle against one another.
This is my first attempt at a webpage and I'm trying to pass an ID to another page.  The problem is that my page_load fires the first time and I set the ViewState variables but then my master page loads which causes everything to be reset.

First page:
FindOpponent.aspx (button click sets the ID and then proceeds to here)

```
 Context.Items["WarID"] = tw.ID;

 Server.Transfer("ConfirmWarTimer.aspx");
```

Second Page:
ConfirmWarTimer.aspx (Everything works the first time Page_Load gets called.  ViewState contains my variable and timer is enabled)

```
protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         {
             ActivateTimer();
             return;
         }
     }
     public void ActivateTimer()
     {
          if (!tim.Enabled)
        {
            DBClassesDataContext db = new DBClassesDataContext();
            if (Context.Items["WarID"] != null)
            {
                ViewState["WarID"] = Context.Items["WarID"];
                var thisWar = from a in db.tblWars where a.ID == int.Parse(ViewState["WarID"].ToString()) select a;
                foreach (var a in thisWar)
                {
                    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(a.CountDown.ToString());

                    ViewState["Hours"] = t.Hours;
                    ViewState["Minutes"] = t.Minutes;
                    ViewState["Seconds"] = t.Seconds;
                    ViewState["TimeStamp"] = a.TimeStamp.ToString();
                }

        }
    lblStart.Value = ViewState["TimeStamp"].ToString();
        tim.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }
     }
```

But then the master page init/preload/load get called.  After that, the Page_Load gets called again on my second page but this time the Context.Items is blank and the ViewState is blank and the timer.enabled is false.

Master Page cs (This is just the page that was created with my project.  I added the page_load so the menu wouldn't show on the default.aspx page.)

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
    var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
    Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
    if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
    {
        // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
        _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
        Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
        _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

        var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
        };
        if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            responseCookie.Secure = true;
        }
        Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
    }

    Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
}

protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Set Anti-XSRF token
        ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
        ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
        if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
            || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().IndexOf("default") > -1))
    {
        pnMenu.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pnMenu.Visible = true;
    }
}

protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
}
```

I've tried to understand viewstate and when to set it and where but after many attempts and changes, viewstate never seems to stick around in my page.

How can I get the viewstate to persist on the second page (ConfirmWarTimer.aspx) after my masterpage 'loads' have executed?

Comment: Remember - ViewStat is a hidden field on the current page.

Comment: Use a Session instead of a Viewstate